WPF - Style that changes button background depending on the IsEnabled property
I made this style for my button and it is loaded fine
but I now try to have a different background depending on the IsEnabled property and this does not seem to work
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Color" Color="#FFADD2CC"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Color_Disabled" Color="#FF8D9B98"/>

<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="32"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4,8,4"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundRect" Fill="{StaticResource Color}" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <!-- DataTrigger to change the background color based on IsEnabled property -->
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="BackgroundRect" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource Color}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="BackgroundRect" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource Color_Disabled}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

I use it in my main template like this
<Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Button Text" ToolTip="Some tooltip" Click="OnClick" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Margin="0,0,4,0" IsEnabled="false"/>

I expect the button to be a different color depending on the IsEnabled value

You only need a single Trigger on the IsEnabled property that sets the Button's Background. The Grid and Rectangle in the ControlTemplate are redundant.
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundEnabled" Color="#FFADD2CC"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundDisabled" Color="#FF8D9B98"/>

<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    ...
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundEnabled}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        CornerRadius="2">
                    <ContentPresenter
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                Value="{StaticResource BackgroundDisabled}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>


yeah but you removed the rectangle with corner radius, I need that

Added CornerRadius="2" to the Border.

Background, BackgroundEnabled ... why two backgrounds ?
